# Themeing for Different Capabilities and Devices

Tags: mobile, themes, wordpress-theming, desktop, tablet

Looking for advice on this - please give your opinion on which is best and the pros and cons.

I've got a site I'm working on that will be catering to basically three types of devices.  Desktop/Laptop, Tablet, Phone.  It is a responsive site so it looks great on all three.

BUT!

For the tablet and the phone there are a couple of features we will be including that will not be available for Desktop.  There are links that will be included just for these and there will be a whole new menu that will sit snugly along the bottom of the site.

AND!

For the phone there will be even more features that will be in that bottom menu (like a "phone" icon to quick call from any page - not on the tablet).

We've got a WURFL setup telling us the device capabilities (is_smartphone, is_tablet, neither) - just want to know what you think is the best way to implement this?

a) set theme based on capability?
b) show/hide certain menus in the CSS based on capability?
c) something else?

Comment: I usually use CSS to make different elements visible on different screen sizes - media queries, i.e mobile.css #main-menu {display:none} #mobile-menu {<styles>} - style.css #main-menu {<styles>} #mobile-menu {display:none} header.php <div id="mobile-menu><html here></div><div id="main-menu"><html here></div>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using server side detection you can deliver specific sets of css and html depending on what type of hardware is creating the httpd request.  The benefit of this over using media queries is you are able to decrease load times.  The issue of doing display none is they are still getting loaded and not displayed.  I would recommend to use the [RESS](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/14/providing-the-best-mobile-user-experience-possible/) technique.